# merge a dataframe based on one column and summing the other columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to merge a dataframe based on one column and summing the others. I have attempted to do this via df.loc combining sum and have searched Stack extensively already. If any of you have suggestions, they are very welcome :)

Original:

| Date | Value x | Value y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13-3-1920 | 1 | 0 |
| 13-3-1920 | 0 | 1 |
| 30-4-1920 | 0 | 1 |
| 30-4-1920 | 1 | 1 |

Desired Output:

| Date | Value x | Value y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13-3-1920 | 1 | 1 |
| 30-4-1920 | 1 | 2 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need a groupby

Comment: `df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).agg({'Value x':'sum', 'Value y':'sum'})`

Comment: @SomeDude your solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"df" is the dataframe. I've considered date column to be of string data type.

The group by function gives the expected output.

```
df.groupby(['date']).sum()
```